# Manage tasks/todos on GitHub?

Tags: github

I am using GitHub for my git repository. Now there are some tasks like "implement feature x" that still have to be done for my app. Is it possible to manage these tasks on GitHub? How? There are issues, but for me issues are problems, bugs, etc. and not tasks - or is my understanding of the term "issue" wrong?

Comment: Use [issues](https://docs.github.com/en/issues), use [projects](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects), include `TODO` comments in the code, have a [checklist](https://github.blog/2014-04-28-task-lists-in-all-markdown-documents/) in the README, ...

Comment: How to use a web site is not programming.

Comment: @matt: check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'm fairly certain this question falls under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" category. Github certainly is such a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Issues" is an implementation of what other websites call tickets and sometimes just bugs.

What you use it for is basically up to you to decide. Bugs are an obvious example, but definitely not the only ones. Github provides tags to provide metadata to issues and one common usage of tags is to indicate what kind of "issue" it is.

As an example Angular has [a feature tag](https://github.com/angular/angular/labels/feature) which they put on issues that are about adding features. Many other project use a similar structure.

Basically: if it will lead to code being merged then it can *definitely* be an issue and you'll benefit from all the inter-linking within Github. Even if it *doesn't* result in code (such as topics related to organization of a project) it might be appropriate to put it into Github issues.

Comment: Thank you. Meanwhile I've also seen this on the Github documentation for issues (https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-issues): "Use GitHub Issues to track ideas, feedback, tasks, or bugs". So issues are the right thing for me :-)

Comment: That's why I generally prefer the more generic name "tickets" for these kinds of things, but most current systems will allow you to track various kinds of things in them, even if they don't use that nomenclature.